# Make content of HorizontalGroup Wrap to the next line in Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I use `libgdx's` `scene2d` built-in UI library to make an UI in my game .
i want to use some component like `div` in html , to add some `TextButton` i've try to use `HorizontalGroup` but when the TextButtons are long the text Exceed the area .
I want to set bounds to this actor (`HorizontalGroup`) to make it limited

here is my code

```
myFunction(){

  HorizontalGroup group=new HorizontalGroup();

        for (...) {


            button =new TextButton(...);

            group.addActor(button);
            group.setDebug(true);
            group.setBounds(5,200,200f,200f);
}
stage.addActor(group);
}
```

and this is the result [my first game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozVV1.png)

any help please

Comment: You want the contents to be cropped? Or wrap to the next line?

Comment: wrap to the next line :)

Comment: That option was just added in the 1.9.5 release this week. Call wrap() on the group.

Comment: Awesome ! it's work thanks

Comment: Note that wrap function is fron release 1.9.4.